Issue in performing inference using onnx converted tensorflow pb model
I am facing in issue in performing inference using a pb model that was converted using an onnx model(end goal is to convert torch to tflite model). My original torch model was converted to onnx model which had no problem in inference. The pb model converted onnx model shows an LSTM related error during inference. I ran the following inference code:
def load_input_image():
 imgh = 120
 imgw = 360
 image_path = 'YRBybNcARj_1717501021400.jpg'
 orig_image = cv2.imread(image_path)
 image = cv2.cvtColor(orig_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 image = image/127.5 - 1.0
 image = cv2.resize(image,(imgw, imgh),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
 image = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
 image = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
 image = np.float32(image)
 image.shape # (1,1,120,360)
 return image


loaded = tf.saved_model.load(f"{repo_dir}/trial.pb")
print(list(loaded.signatures.keys()))  # ["serving_default"]

infer = loaded.signatures['serving_default']

print("output description: ", infer.structured_outputs)
# output description:  {'output': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 89, 12), dtype=tf.float32, name='output')}


infer(tf.constant(image))
#THIS IS THE ERROR:
Detected at node 'LSTM_d2b678f9/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/while/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/BiasAdd' defined at (most recent call last):
Node: 'LSTM_d2b678f9/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/while/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/BiasAdd'
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,512], In[1]: [768,1024]
     [[{{node LSTM_d2b678f9/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/while/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/BiasAdd}}]] [Op:__inference_signature_wrapper_8182]

My pytorch model definition is as below.
opt.input_channel = 1
opt.hidden_size = 256
opt.output_channel = 512
class Model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, opt):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.opt = opt
        self.stages = {'Trans': None, 'Feat': 'VGG',
                       'Seq': 'BiLSTM', 'Pred': 'CTC'}

        #self.avgpoolcustom = AdaptiveAvgPool2dCustom(output_size=(512,1))
        
        #self.avg_pool = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(1, 6), stride=(1, 6))
        
        """ Transformation """
        if opt.Transformation == 'TPS':
            self.Transformation = TPS_SpatialTransformerNetwork(
                F=opt.num_fiducial, I_size=(opt.imgH, opt.imgW), I_r_size=(opt.imgH, opt.imgW), I_channel_num=opt.input_channel)
        else:
            print('No Transformation module specified')

        """ FeatureExtraction """
        if opt.FeatureExtraction == 'VGG':
            self.FeatureExtraction = VGG_FeatureExtractor(opt.input_channel, opt.output_channel)
        elif opt.FeatureExtraction == 'RCNN':
            self.FeatureExtraction = RCNN_FeatureExtractor(opt.input_channel, opt.output_channel)
        elif opt.FeatureExtraction == 'ResNet':
            self.FeatureExtraction = ResNet_FeatureExtractor(opt.input_channel, opt.output_channel)
        else:
            raise Exception('No FeatureExtraction module specified')
        self.FeatureExtraction_output = opt.output_channel  # int(imgH/16-1) * 512
        self.AdaptiveAvgPool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((None, 1))  # Transform final (imgH/16-1) -> 1

        """ Sequence modeling"""
        if opt.SequenceModeling == 'BiLSTM':
            self.SequenceModeling = nn.Sequential(
                BidirectionalLSTM(self.FeatureExtraction_output, opt.hidden_size, opt.hidden_size),
                BidirectionalLSTM(opt.hidden_size, opt.hidden_size, opt.hidden_size))
            self.SequenceModeling_output = opt.hidden_size
        else:
            print('No SequenceModeling module specified')
            self.SequenceModeling_output = self.FeatureExtraction_output

        """ Prediction """
        if opt.Prediction == 'CTC':
            self.Prediction = nn.Linear(self.SequenceModeling_output, opt.num_class)
        elif opt.Prediction == 'Attn':
            self.Prediction = Attention(self.SequenceModeling_output, opt.hidden_size, opt.num_class)
        else:
            raise Exception('Prediction is neither CTC or Attn')

    def forward(self, input, is_train=False):
        input = input.detach() #shape: (1,120,360)
        """ Transformation stage """
        #if not self.stages['Trans'] == "None":
        #    input = self.Transformation(input)
        
        #Shape after feature extraction: torch.Size([1, 512, 6, 89])
        # Shape after permute: torch.Size([1,89,512,6])
        #Shape after avg pooling:  torch.Size([1, 89, 512, 1])
        #Shape after squeeze:  torch.Size([1, 89, 512])

        """ Feature extraction stage """
        visual_feature = self.FeatureExtraction(input) #Shape here:  torch.Size([1, 512, 6, 89])
        print("Shape after feature extraction: ", visual_feature.shape)
        
        #original
        #visual_feature = self.AdaptiveAvgPool(visual_feature.permute(0, 3, 1, 2))  # [b, c, h, w] -> [b, w, c, h]
        
        
        #visual_feature = self.avgpoolcustom(visual_feature.permute(0, 3, 1, 2))
        
        #visual_feature = self.avg_pool(visual_feature.permute(0, 3, 1, 2))
  
        visual_feature = torch.mean(visual_feature.permute(0, 3, 1, 2), axis = 3)
        
        print("Shape after avg pooling: ", visual_feature.shape)
        #visual_feature = visual_feature.permute(0, 3, 1, 2) # this makes it [1,89]
        #visual_feature = visual_feature.squeeze(3)
        #print("Shape after squeeze: ", visual_feature.shape, "\n\n")


        # Tensor shape here: (1,89,512)
        """ Sequence modeling stage """
        if self.stages['Seq'] == 'BiLSTM':
            contextual_feature = self.SequenceModeling(visual_feature)
        else:
            contextual_feature = visual_feature  # for convenience. this is NOT contextually modeled by BiLSTM

        """ Prediction stage """
        if self.stages['Pred'] == 'CTC':
            prediction = self.Prediction(contextual_feature.contiguous())
        #else:
        #    prediction = self.Prediction(contextual_feature.contiguous(), text, is_train, batch_max_length=self.opt.batch_max_length)
            
        return prediction.detach()

This is how I converted pytorch to onnx:
def export_onnx_model(destpath, imgh = 120, imgw = 360):
    input = torch.randn(1, 1, imgh, imgw).detach()
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        # Export the model
        torch.onnx.export(model,               # model being run
                        input,                         # model input 
                        destpath,   
                        export_params=True,        
                        opset_version=11,          # the ONNX version to export the model to
                        do_constant_folding=True,  # whether to execute constant folding
                        input_names = ['input'],   # the model's input names
                        output_names = ['output'], # the model's output names
                      )

Finally, this is how I am converting onnx model to pb model:
def convert_onnx_to_pb(onnx_model_path, dest_path):
    onnx_model = onnx.load(onnx_model_path)
    tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)
    print("Exporting to pb model")
    tf_rep.export_graph(dest_path)

Would appreciate any help in solving this.

The error  indicates that the LSTM  have incompatible input dimensions. To fix this shape mismatch, check the input tensor shape to ensure it matches the expected input shape of the TensorFlow model and adjust the model for compatibility. And try re-exporting the ONNX model with different opset_version. And also confirm that the TensorFlow LSTM layer's dimensions match the PyTorch model.
